# Vector, array of image with different sizes

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having a problem using vector,

I am hoping to use vector only instead of array. Eg. below shows the usage of an array.

```
IplImage* bdrInt[a] = cvCreateImage(cvSize(cImg.at(a)->width+2*left, 
cImg.at(a)->height+2*top), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

1. The image size varies.
2. If I'm planning to use vector instead of array. Is it possible? (cvCreateImage do not allow conversion from IplImage to vector type)Is there any workaround for this type?

Comment: 1. What is your definition of "vector"; 2. What is your definition of "array". 3. Do you program in C or in C++?

Comment: For example, I have stored sequence of images with different sizes in a vector (vector<IplImage*> cImg;) previously. I plan to use vector all the way without using array (IplImage* cImg[30]={NULL};). I use C API (use IplImage instead of Mat, because not familiar with C++ API).

Comment: Switch to the C++ API. There is easy conversion between std::vector and cv::Mat. It even does not involve data copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to save the `IplImage` pointers in `vector<IplImage *>`. The vector just stores the pointer, and it doesn't care about the image size.

```
vector<IplImage*> bdrInt;
bdrInt.push_back( cvCreateImage(cvSize(cImg.at(a)->width+2*left, cImg.at(a)->height+2*top), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1) );
```

Comment: Hi luhb, thanks for your answer. I'll marked it as the answer. ;)